# Issue with Type Hinting Return Values and Use Statments

Tags: php, types, php-7

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error in my code.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace Db;

use \PDO\PDOStatement;

function getStmt(string $sql, $pdo): PDOStatement
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Here's the error:

> TypeError: Return value of Db\getStmt() must be an instance of PDO\PDOStatement, instance of PDOStatement returned

The use statement seems to be messing up the checking of the return type. If I get rid of the use statement, the error looks like this, because now it assumes PDOStatment to be a part of the current namespace:

> TypeError: Return value of Db\getStmt() must be an instance of Db\PDOStatement, instance of PDOStatement returned

If I get rid of the namespace and the use statement, it doesn't complain, but I want both of those statements, and really don't understand what's wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is correct but `$pdo->prepare` is returning [`\PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) which is not `\PDO\PDOStatement`. It would help to give `$pdo` a type.

That's why there's no error if you change the return type to `\PDOStatement`.

Comment: Ah, so PDOStatment just isn't in a PDO namespace. Derp, thank you.

Comment: @CarlShiles You're welcome. That's how PHP namespaces used to be until the language supported them but they never changed `\PDOStatement` to `\PDO\Statement`.